# Why my C code is giving me "segmentation fault" error when I try to read dynamically allocated array contents?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

As the question explains, I'm creating a dynamically allocated array of structures(as i called, struct Desk*) in my C code. In the main function, I am giving int id numbers in the "int deskId" fields of them .When I try to read their id's inside the main function, code works as expected. On the other hand, if I try to read their id contents outside the main (as in the code below) it gives segmentation fault(core dumped) error. I am giving the problematic code below. As you see, I paid attention to give the address of the array parameter,(i.e. pointer to the actual array) so that i can read the actual content of the array, no the local copy. 
Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

struct Desk {
    int deskId;
    Queue deskQueue;
};

struct TaxPayer {
    int id;             // tax payer ID
    float duration;     // payment duration
};

//function to display the ids of the desks
int display (int desks, struct Desk** argsptr) {
    int i=0;
    while(i < desks) {
       printf ("My argument's id is %d\n",argsptr[i]->deskId );
       i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int option_index = 0;
    int p_num = 20;
    int desk_num = 4;
    int max_q_size = 3;


 //initialize array of desks
  struct Desk* desk_array = malloc(desk_num * sizeof(struct Desk));
  for (int i= 0; i < desk_num; i++) {
    queueInit(&desk_array[i].deskQueue, sizeof(struct TaxPayer));
    desk_array[i].deskId = i;
  }

  display(desk_num, &desk_array);
  free(desk_array);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the address of the `desk_array` pointer to `display()` rather than the pointer itself. `display()` is then reading the pointer, then the area of memory after the pointer, etc. What you want to do is pass the pointer `desk_array`, and then use `.` rather than `->` inside the function because the `[i]` dereferences `desk_array`.

```
int display (int desks, struct Desk* argsptr) {
    int i=0;
    while(i < desks) {
       printf ("My argument's id is %d\n",argsptr[i].deskId );
       i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

...

```
display(desk_num, desk_array);
```

Comment: You are right. I believed that it was necessary to give array with its address so that i can change the original copy, but surprisingly your suggestion also reaches the actual array (not the local copy).

Answer (score 1):

`argsptr[i]->deskId` accesses an array of `struct Desk *`, but there is only one. You need `(*argsptr)[i].deskId`.

Alternatively, pass `desk_array` instead of `&desk_array`, change the parameter type to `struct Desk *`, and use `argsptr[i].deskId`.